# How to select dynamic select option value using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<select  class="select" data-ng-model="sites.webSites.addable.languages"
ng-options="language as language.label for language in languages" >
                                                    </select>

$scope.languages = [
             {
                 value : 'lang_en',
                 label : 'English-en'
             },
             {
                 value : 'lang_es',
                 label : 'Spanish-es'
             },
             ];
```

Clicking on a button I have to make the item selected

I have tried like this

```
var sitevalue = 'lang_es'//dynamic

$('.select').val(sitevalue);
```

But it is not working ,please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your select to something like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="sites.language"
    ng-options="language.value as language.label for language in languages" ></select>
```

Then this should work inside your controller:

```
sites.language = 'lang_es'
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uay1d5ey/)

**Update:**

When you are writing `language as language.label for ...` you are telling angular to map `ng-model` to object like `{ value : '...', label : '...' }`. Which would be tracked per reference, means you have to assign to ng-model exacltly the same instance that you specified. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/) from angular team illustrating this.

You can use simple assignments to value propery to cange selected value by using this inside ng-options: `language.value as language.label for ...`

And you don't want to write jquery selectors or manipulate DOM, try avoid `$('.select').val(sitevalue);` when using angular. Use native js-models instead and rely on framework to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be set to the exact object (by reference) that you would like to select, not only to the value.

Make you HTML like this:

```
  <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <select  class="select" ng-options=" language.label for language in languages" ng-model="selectedValue"></select>
    <button ng-click="selectedValue = defaultValue">Select Default</button>
  </body>
```

and your controller like this:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.languages = [
   {
       value : 'lang_en',
       label : 'English-en'
   },
   {
       value : 'lang_es',
       label : 'Spanish-es'
   },
   ];
   $scope.selectedValue = {};
   $scope.defaultValue = $scope.languages[1];
}
```

This will do the job. Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8HrQUGMx4jGmJv3fbdDq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.sites.webSites.addable.languages = 'lang_es';
```

selected value is associated with `data-ng-model`

Answer (score 0):

1. ng-options should be "language.value as language.label for language in languages".
2. data-ng-model (or just ng-model) should be "selectedLanguageValue".
3. In the controller, get the value of $scope.selectedLanguageValue.